# What does rails load before a minitest? (very slow tests with rails 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, minitest

I have a very simple test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class InformationRequestTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'valid information request can be saved' do
    FactoryBot.create(:information_request)
  end
end
```

In rails 5.2 this test takes 14 seconds

In rails 6.0 this test takes 159 seconds

I used Benchmark to measure `test_helper` and it takes 3 seconds (in rails 6) to load, and the test itself is also just a few seconds. So something before the test is taking over 2 minutes to load... but what is it? How do I follow Rails' steps to find out exactly what's taking so long?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this? We're experiencing similar problems

Comment: @Barry no sorry, I think it was related to having fixtures, could also be related to Spring, but yea it's a still a mystery